# why you don't Implement PDO for access every thing to database

Tags: database, mysql, sql

that is.. why wordpress don´t use PDO if it is more secure, and prevent a lot of injections, and issues with security.

Thakns

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need PDO to write safe DB queries. PHP developers were able to do so before PDO was created ;)

There is nothing unsafe in using `WPDB` class, as long as you do it correctly (just use prepare and correct ways of escaping).

There is one major flaw in your question: using PDO, of course, doesn’t make you secure - you still can write unsafe code ;) That’s why you can find SQL Injection vulnerabilities also in software that uses PDO (or even ORMs).

So I don’t see any reason for arguing why WP doesn’t use PDO. Much better (and more up to date) would be a question: “Why is there no ORM impelementation in WP” ;)